# how can I merge lists to create a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have tried many methods to do this but could not find a working solution. In this problem, I have two python arrays and I would like to join them to create a big dictionary. It would go something like this:

```
`list1 = [
[2, "ford"],
[4,"Ferrari"],
[3, "Mercedes"],
[1, "BMW"]
]`

`list2 = [
[4, "mustang"],
[3,"LaFerrari"],
[2,"CLA"],
[1,"M5"],
[6,"opel"]
]`
```

The result that I would like to have is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
`result = {
1: ["BMW","M5"], 2: ["Ford","CLA"], 3: ["Mercedes","LaFerrari"], 4: ["Ferrari","Mustang"], 6:["Opel"]
}`
```

So it just basically needs to merge these two arrays based on the "key" (which is just the [0] place in the array)

Comment: Will both lists have all of the same keys?

Comment: well there can be some keys that are different,like there could be for example another entry in list2 with values 5, "Opel" and that would have to be added to the dictionary too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a `dict` using the values in `list1`. Then update the `list`s in the `dict` with the values from `list2`, or create new `list`s for the keys in `list2` which don't exist in `list1`:

```
result = {i: [j] for i, j in list1} # create initial dict from all values in list1
for i, j in list2:
    if i in result:
        result[i].append(j) # add to preexisting list corresponding to key
    else:
        result[i] = [j] # create new list corresponding to key
```

If your `list`s will have multiple values, you can use this where you handle the add logic in a separate function:

```
result = {}
def add_to_dict(d, key, val):
    if key in d:
        d[key].append(val)
    else:
        d[key] = [val]

for el in (list1 + list2):
    key, *vals = el
    for val in vals:
        add_to_dict(result, key, val)
```

Here, rather than assuming each sublist has only 2 elements, we can unpack the key as the first element and the rest of the elements into a `list` called `vals`. Then, we can iterate over the `list` and perform the same adding logic

Comment: thanks,that works perfectly,I just have one more question,how could you make this work for a list that have more entries, like for example if there were not just 2 values in each subarraylike now(2,"ford"), but now you would have (2,"ford","GMC") and so for every subarray

Comment: @py_learner1 no problem, I just added an edit for your second case

Answer (score 1):

It looks like task for `collections.defaultdict` I would do:

```
import collections
list1 = [
[1, "ford"],
[2,"Ferrari"],
[3, "Mercedes"],
[4, "BMW"]
]
list2 = [
[1, "mustang"],
[2,"LaFerrari"],
[3,"CLA"],
[4,"M5"]
]
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in list1:
    result[key].append(value)
for key, value in list2:
    result[key].append(value)
result = dict(result)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{1: ['ford', 'mustang'], 2: ['Ferrari', 'LaFerrari'], 3: ['Mercedes', 'CLA'], 4: ['BMW', 'M5']}
```

Here I used `defaultdict` with `list`s, unlike common `dict` if you try do something with value under key which do not exist yet, it did place `list()` i.e. empty `list`, then do requested action (`append`ing in this case). At end I convert it into `dict` just to fullfill your requirement (*create a python dictionary*).

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in list1 + list2:
    result[k].append(v)

print (dict(result))
#{2: ['ford', 'CLA'], 4: ['Ferrari', 'mustang'], 3: ['Mercedes', 'LaFerrari'], 1: ['BMW', 'M5'], 6: ['opel']}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also pretty new to Python, but I think something like this should work if both lists have the same keys:

```
list1 = [
    [1, "ford"],
    [2, "Ferrari"],
    [3, "Mercedes"],
    [4, "BMW"]
]
list2 = [
    [1, "mustang"],
    [2, "LaFerrari"],
    [3, "CLA"],
    [4, "M5"]
]
dict1 = dict(list1)
dict2 = dict(list2)
result = {}
for key,val in dict1.items():
    result[key] = [val]
for key, val in dict2.items():
    result[key].append(val)
print(result)
```

> output

```
{1: ['ford', 'mustang'], 2: ['Ferrari', 'LaFerrari'], 3: ['Mercedes', 'CLA'], 4: ['BMW', 'M5']}
```

As already mentioned, I am a newbie too, so there is probably a more "pythonic" way of doing this.

Comment: your solution will work as long as keys of dict2 are subset of keys of dict1 or speaking python: `set(dict2.keys()).issubset(dict1.keys())` - this does hold true for example data provided, but does not force that both dicts have exactly same keys, for example it would work if dict1 have keys `1,2,3` and dict2 have keys `1,2`

Comment: Sure, you are of course right. This is why I mentioned that it only works if both lists have the same keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that both lists contain the same number of items and both has a matching first element in each item (1, 2, 3, 4 in your example),

```
result =  {k: [dict(list1)[k], dict(list2)[k]] for k in dict(list1)}
```